# Compare column with itself in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['Mohit', 'Mimansa', 'Viseshini', 'Manoj', 'Manojj', 'Mohith', 'Mimi', 'Visesheni']})
df

names
0   Mohit
1   Mimansa
2   Viseshini
3   Manoj
4   Manojj
5   Mohith
6   Mimi
7   Visesheni
```

I am trying to compare each string with the remaining strings in the other columns

I have a function partial_ratio which takes two strings and returns a similarity percentage:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
fuzz.partial_ratio('Mohit', 'Moht Motwani')
>>80
```

What I want is the index of the rows where the string match is at least 80%.

I have tried this:

```
ratios = []
for row in df['names']:
    vals = df['names'].apply(lambda x: fuzz.partial_ratio(x, row))
    ratios.append(np.where(vals>80))
ratios

[(array([0, 5], dtype=int64),),
 (array([1], dtype=int64),),
 (array([2, 7], dtype=int64),),
 (array([3, 4], dtype=int64),),
 (array([3, 4], dtype=int64),),
 (array([0, 5], dtype=int64),),
 (array([6], dtype=int64),),
 (array([2, 7], dtype=int64),)]
```

There are two problems:

1) I'm using the for loop so it makes the operation very slow for bigger datasets. Each string is compared with every other using the apply function of a series and another series is returned. The indexes of at least 80% matches are retrieved with `np.where`.

2) When I use the apply function the string also compares to itself..

Is there a pandas function/method or a better way to achieve this:

```
   names     matches
0   Mohit        [5]
1   Mimansa      []
2   Viseshini    [7]
3   Manoj        [4]
4   Manojj       [3]
5   Moht Motwani [0]
6   Mimi         []
7   Visesheni    [2]
```

Comment: use `itertuples` to iterate. Also why not subtract one from final column if list isn't empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop and list from list comprehension convert to `numpy array`, so possible filterinf with `numpy.where` and then filter out same indices with boolean indexing, indices are created by `enumerate`:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

ratios = []
for i, x in enumerate(df['names']):
    a = np.array([fuzz.partial_ratio(x, row) for row in df['names']])
    a = np.where(a > 80)[0]
    ratios.append(a[a != i])

df['rat'] = ratios
print (df)

       names  rat
0      Mohit  [5]
1    Mimansa   []
2  Viseshini  [7]
3      Manoj  [4]
4     Manojj  [3]
5     Mohith  [0]
6       Mimi   []
7  Visesheni  [2]
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. Can you also explain your answer?

Comment: @MohitMotwani - working for better one, give me  asec

Comment: @MohitMotwani - hmmm, I see 2 answers, best test it with real data. But main problem here is `fuzz.partial_ratio` working with scalars, so loops are necessary `for` or `apply` (`apply` are also loops under the hood, hard to know if better like `for` - the best test it)

Answer (score 1):

Use the below chunk of code, so simply just do bunch of stuff for your desired output, it maybe unreadable, but still works as expected, bunch of `apply`s and funky code :-):

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pandas as pd
import random,ast
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['Mohit', 'Mimansa', 'Viseshini', 'Manoj', 'Manojj', 'Mohith', 'Mimi', 'Visesheni']})
it=iter(range(len(df['names'])))
df['matches']=df['names'].apply(lambda x: [i for i,v in enumerate(df['names']) if fuzz.partial_ratio(v,x)>80] if len([i for i,v in enumerate(df['names']) if fuzz.partial_ratio(v,x)>80])>1 else [])
df['matches']=df['matches'].astype(str)
df['count'] = df.groupby('matches').cumcount() + 1
df['matches']=df['matches'].map(ast.literal_eval)
df['matches']=df.apply(lambda x: ([x['matches'][-1]] if x['count']==1 else [x['matches'][0]]) if x['matches']!=[] else x['matches'],axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       names matches  count
0      Mohit     [5]      1
1    Mimansa      []      1
2  Viseshini     [7]      1
3      Manoj     [4]      1
4     Manojj     [3]      2
5     Mohith     [0]      2
6       Mimi      []      2
7  Visesheni     [2]      2
```

To explain:

- Create a `apply` statement for getting index as expected
- Make a `groupby` for getting counts of the values, every value is being counted until the row that the value exists
- Then do bunch of stuff to update `'matches'` column, and remove the duplicate issue

Comment: @MohitMotwani Will do.